# How to center elements in emailtemplates correctly?

Tags: html, css

Why does the last element(picture) show correctly in outlook but not in gmail? I want it to be centered.
Why do emailclients display html differently and how can i adjust for this?

```
<div style='margin: 20px; width: 80% padding: 10px;'>
 <div style='text-align:center'>
   <h1>Welcome, customer</h1>
 </div>
 <p>Thank you for subscribing to my mailing list. bla bla bla...</p> 
 <div style='text-align: center'>
   <h2><a href='http://something.com'>Link to something</a></h2>
   <p>Please click the link</p>
 </div>
   <br /><br />
 <div style='text-align:center;'>
   <img src='https://www.nnlskyen.no/images/nnlnew.jpg' alt='img' width='170' height:'75' border='0' style='display: block; width: 170px; align: center;' />
   <br />
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `display: block` to `inline-block`

```
<div style='text-align:center;'>
   <img src='https://www.nnlskyen.no/images/nnlnew.jpg' alt='img' width='170' height:'75' border='0' style='display: inline-block; width: 170px; align: center;' />
   <br />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

**HTML**

```
    <div style='margin: 20px; width: 80%; padding: 10px;text-align:center;'>
 <div style='text-align:center'>
   <h1>Welcome, customer</h1>
 </div>
 <p>Thank you for subscribing to my mailing list. bla bla bla...</p> 
 <div>
   <h2><a href='http://something.com'>Link to something</a></h2>
   <p>Please click the link</p>
 </div>
   <br /><br />
 <div>
   <img src='https://www.nnlskyen.no/images/nnlnew.jpg' alt='img' width='170' height:'75' border='0' style='width: 170px; align: center;' />
   <br />
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't want all the text to be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Use inline-block. height and width with %.

```
<div style='text-align:center;'>
   <img src='https://www.nnlskyen.no/images/nnlnew.jpg' alt='img' height:'50%' border='0' style='display: inline-block; width:'50%' ; align: center;' />
   <br />
 </div>
```